# Targeting div without class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There a piece of text on a website that I'm helping to manage that I need to change. I do not have access to the html so I cannot put classes or ids on anything nor can I just change the text that way. That would make things way too easy!

So, I need to change the text "No Animals Found!" to something else and the only way I can do it is through javascript/jquery.

The below code does work, however it works a little too well. It's actually selecting other elements on other pages and changing them as well. such as

```
<div align="center" class="boxedLinks">[ <a href="/admin/content/edit_content?Location=Header">Edit Page Header</a> ]</div>
```

Is there a way to only select that one particular div?

Any help would be awesome!!

```js
$('#Page88').find('div:contains(No Animals Found!)').text("Hold on! Our kittens have to grow a bit more before they'll be ready for adoption!")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='Page88'>
  <td width="100%" valign="top">
    <div id="PageHeader">
    </div>

    <div id="fullSize">
      <div class="hd"></div>
      <div class="bd"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageCenterTitle">Kittens</div>

    <div align="center">
      <a href="/animals/search">Animal Search</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>


    <!-- Begin Bottom Layout -->
    <div id="PageFooter">

    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </td>

</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be the second div with attribute `align`. Is it always going to be that exact div or will the format change however?

Comment: When I run the code snippet on this question it looks like it targets only that one specific `div`.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @A.Lau It shouldn't change, however I have no control over the html.

Comment: @David, I did not include the other sections that were changing. As it was changing in other parts of the website

Comment: @Santi `.text()` is not read-only

Comment: @Santi, It was changing other parts of my website as well. So, that was not fine... I need to be a bit more specific I guess?

Comment: I'm kind of confused as `.text()` works well even on this snippet is working .

Comment: Yeah I was mistaken, just redacted that. Anyways, @zazvorniki, your question does *not* demonstrate an issue. As per the MCVE, your answer must be *verifiable* - as in, the issue is *clearly reproduced in your example*. While you could use additional selectors like `.first()` or even `.eq()`, we can't possibly know which to use without either a verifiable example or a bit more information.

Comment: @julekgwa The problem is that while the example works (as I stated in the question) it is also changing other parts of the website because it is not specific enough.

Comment: @Santi I cannot post my entire website here though. It was changing other text on other pages.

Comment: Your simplified issue is: "I need a selector that *doesn't select other divs*", but then you're *not showing us the other divs*. See what I'm getting at? I'm not asking for the entire website, but we need at least one more div. Until then, all answers will be guesses.

Comment: Use this code $('#Page88 #PageFooter').prev().text('No Animals Found!')

Comment: @zazvorniki I'd suggest atleast post one or two more areas of your html where the text is also changing. Based on current html, the code works perfectly fine. Otherwise you will keep getting random answers like above.

Comment: I've posted above one of the snippets it's changing

Comment: @zazvorniki Your selector should *not* be selecting your example div - are you sure that's the case? https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/tkv5xzy0/ - The fact that someone suggested using `.first()`, and it *still* updated multiple divs, leads me to believe that your issue is a different line of code.

Comment: @Santi, yes I am sure. I can give you the live website if you want. That is why this is so odd/weird.

Comment: The :contains() selector selects elements containing the specified string.
The string can be contained directly in the element as text, or in a child element. This means the div being selected could be a parent or the grand parent of the desired DIV and hence everything inside may change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way using regular expression and the method [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) that will replace only the vert first occurrence in the [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) content of `#Page88`:

```js
$('#Page88').html(function () {
    return $(this)
      .html()
      .replace(
        'No Animals Found!', 
        'Hold on! Our kittens have to grow a bit more before they\'ll be ready for adoption!'
      ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='Page88'>
  <td width="100%" valign="top">
    <div id="PageHeader">
    </div>

    <div id="fullSize">
      <div class="hd"></div>
      <div class="bd"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="pageCenterTitle">Kittens</div>

    <div align="center">
      <a href="/animals/search">Animal Search</a>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    <br>

    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>
    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>
    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>

    <!-- Begin Bottom Layout -->
    <div id="PageFooter"></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </td>

</div>
```

And another way is to iterate over all `div`s elements doing a comparison `str.notFound === $(div).text()` and keeping track with a `boolean` variable:

```js
var isReplaced = false,
    str = {};

str.notFound = 'No Animals Found!',
str.replaceWith = 'Hold on! Our kittens have to grow a bit more before they\'ll be ready for adoption!';
    
$('#Page88')
  .find('div')
  .each(function(index, div) {
    if (!isReplaced && str.notFound === $(div).text()) {
      $(div).text(str.replaceWith);
      isReplaced = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='Page88'>
  <td width="100%" valign="top">
    <div id="PageHeader">
    </div>

    <div id="fullSize">
      <div class="hd"></div>
      <div class="bd"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="pageCenterTitle">Kittens</div>

    <div align="center">
      <a href="/animals/search">Animal Search</a>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    <br>

    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>
    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>
    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>

    <!-- Begin Bottom Layout -->
    <div id="PageFooter"></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </td>

</div>
```

Comment: @zazvorniki it is Good to help

Answer (score 1):

you can add `.first()` in your jquery selection code to get the first `div` that contains 'No Animals Found!' or something like that

(hard to say exactly what until we see what code its changing that its not supposed to be changing, but this gives you an example of how it would work)

```js
$('#Page88').find('div:contains(No Animals Found!)').first().text("Hold on! Our kittens have to grow a bit more before they'll be ready for adoption!")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='Page88'>
  <td width="100%" valign="top">
    <div id="PageHeader">
    </div>

    <div id="fullSize">
      <div class="hd"></div>
      <div class="bd"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageCenterTitle">Kittens</div>

    <div align="center">
      <a href="/animals/search">Animal Search</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>
    <div align="center" class="boxedLinks">[ <a href="/admin/content/edit_content?Location=Header">Edit Page Header</a> ]</div>

    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>
    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>
    <!-- Begin Bottom Layout -->
    <div id="PageFooter">

    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </td>

</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still changes other sections of code. I believe the issue is with the contains. It is also changing an href

Comment: @zazvorniki what section of code does it change other than this? if you can provide that information, we'll be able to help you with your issue

Comment: <div align="center" class="boxedLinks">[ <a href="/admin/content/edit_content?Location=Header">Edit Page Header</a> ]</div> It's in my question.

Comment: @zazvorniki hmm i added it in the code snippet of my answer and jquery code doesnt seem to target it at all. this is quite odd. have you been able to replicate this issue in an isolated environment (cause there could be some other javascript changing the other divs instead of the one you think is the issue).

Answer (score 0):

I will add the align=center as the identifier and get the first DIV, just to make sure is the only one you want to change:

```js
$('#Page88').find('div:contains("No Animals Found!")[align="center"]').first().text("Hold on! Our kittens have to grow a bit more before they'll be ready for adoption!")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='Page88'>
  <td width="100%" valign="top">
    <div id="PageHeader">
    </div>

    <div id="fullSize">
      <div class="hd"></div>
      <div class="bd"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageCenterTitle">Kittens</div>

    <div align="center">
      <a href="/animals/search">Animal Search</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>
    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>
    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>
    <div align="center">No Animals Found!</div>


    <!-- Begin Bottom Layout -->
    <div id="PageFooter">

    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </td>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/ct2jsds2/4/

Comment: There is only one element on the page. The problem arises with this changing other pages elements.

Comment: Correct, if you try the code you will see that this code will target just the first element that has "No Animals Found" with the align="center" property in it.

Comment: Yes, but that was not my issue. The main problem is it is changing another element on another page

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```js
$("div:contains(test)").css("border", "1px solid red");
```

```css
div {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By using `div:contains`, you're going to update the selected div *and every single one of its parents*, being that they *all* contain the text you're looking for.

Because the selector will find the specific div you're looking for *last*, you probably don't want `.first()` - you want `.last()`.

---

Consider our example now, using `.last()`:

```js
$("div:contains(test)").last().css("border", "1px solid red");
```

```css
div {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Your code would be as follows:

```
$('#Page88').find('div:contains(No Animals Found!)').last().text("Hold on! Our kittens have to grow a bit more before they'll be ready for adoption!")
```